# Separating rows of data containing multiple non-zeros, so new rows contain one non-zero value each

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataset like this:

```r
df1 <- cbind(c("a","b"),c("c","c"),c(0,8),c(4,0),c(5,0),c(0,12))
colnames(df1) <- c("name1","name2","v1","v2","v3","v4")

name1 name2 v1 v2 v3 v4
    a     c  0  4  5  0
    b     c  8  0  0 12
```

But I need to create new rows so that the non-zero values of pairs of names have their own row like this:

```r
df2 <- cbind(c("a","a","b","b"),c("c","c","c","c"),c(0,0,8,0),c(4,0,0,0),c(0,5,0,0),c(0,0,0,12))
colnames(df2) <- c("name1","name2","v1","v2","v3","v4")

name1 name2 v1 v2 v3 v4
    a     c  0  4  0  0
    a     c  0  0  5  0
    b     c  8  0  0  0
    b     c  0  0  0 12
```

This is my first question so I hope that's enough detail.  I've tried `separate_rows`, and `mutate` `if_else`, but I'm completely stumped.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

```r
library(tidyverse)

df1 |>
  as_tibble() |>
  pivot_longer(
    cols = starts_with("v"),
    names_to = 'var',
    values_to = 'value'
  ) |>
  filter(value != 0) |>
  mutate(
    var2 = var  # dummy variable to trick `pivot_wider` to do what you want
  ) |>
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = var,
    values_from = value,
    values_fill = "0"  # values are forced to be characters due to how data is entered/saved.  Might need to change to 0 (without the quotes) in your real data.
  ) |>
select(-var2) # remove dummy variable
```

Answer (score 1):

A `data.table` `melt` and `dcast`:

```
library(data.table)

dcast(
  melt(setDT(df1), c("name1", "name2"))[value != 0],
  name1 + name2 + value ~ variable, fill = 0,
)[, value := NULL][]
#>    name1 name2 v1 v2 v3 v4
#> 1:     a     c  0  4  0  0
#> 2:     a     c  0  0  5  0
#> 3:     b     c  8  0  0  0
#> 4:     b     c  0  0  0 12
```

Data:

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  name1 = c("a","b"),
  name2 = c("c","c"),
  v1 = c(0,8),
  v2 = c(4,0),
  v3 = c(5,0),
  v4 = c(0,12)
)
```

Comment: Appreciate it very much :)